# How can I automatically answer yes on a CMD Prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

I tried to delete the vss shadow copies via cmd and it asks for a prompt y/n. How do I automatically answer yes?

This is the syntax:

```
echo y | vssadmin delete shadows /all > C:\Temp\VssDeleteDriveC.log
```

This is the result of the syntax entered:

> ```
> vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
> (C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Do you really want to delete 1 shadow copies (Y/N): [N]? N
> ```

[image]

Comment: It is not the CMD prompt but the command/tool that supports, usually of name `Force`, an automation not to show confirmation messages. You should check if vssadmin has such switch.

Comment: Have you tried `echo Y| vssadmin …` (no space in front of the pipe, which is otherwise also echoed out)?

Comment: @aschipfl tried it but it has the same output

Comment: Another way: `< nul set /P ="Y" | vssadmin …` (in contrast to `echo Y`, this does not append a line-break)

Comment: Did you try `/quiet` already? Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/vssadmin-delete-shadows.

Comment: Piping input to an executable would only work if said executable gets that input from standard input. (If it doesn't, then piping input to it won't work.)

Comment: Yes, @Bill_Stewart, but wouldn't the program still await the prompt then rather than just continue with `N`?

Comment: That depends on the behavior of the executable.